# Related table attribute in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have two related table in my rails application: `ephemerides` and `ephemeris_shared_attributes`.

The first one has an `ephemedis_shared_attribute_id` column and the seconds has columns as `year`, `yday` etc.

An `ephemeris_shared_attributes` is created automatically when I save an ephemeris but there is no value in it.

How can I add a form field to enter for example year and save it in the `ephemeris_shared_attributes table`?

Here is my current form:

```
= form_for @ephemeris do |f|

... 


.field
    = f.label :content
    = f.text_area :content
  .field
    = f.label :locale
    = f.select(:locale,['mg','fr'])
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this line in your model Ephemerides:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ephemedis_shared_attribute
```

Then in your form:

```
= form @ephemeris do |f|
  ...
  = f.fields_for :ephemedis_shared_attribute do |f2|
    .field
      = f2.label :year
      = f2.text_field :year
  ...
```

Hope I didn't spoil variables, these ephme...things are a little confusing :D